# How can I shift my mindset from engineering to research

Tags: research-process, engineering

How can I shift my mindset from viewing my research project solely as an engineering project, given my background and extensive experience in software engineering, to better embrace the research culture and mindset as I pursue a Ph.D. degree, overcoming challenges and avoiding strict adherence to engineering aspects?

The main point is about my supervisor; he always criticizes me for setting a plan, defining the scope, and outlining early on. He claims that it limits my imagination, innovation, and potential, insisting that I should keep things more exploratory.

Comment: What is wrong with treating it mainly as an engineering project? Doesn't an engineering project overcome challenges? In experimental physical sciences one often has to get things done and working just to take the data you are really after.

Comment: The main problem is with my supervisor he always criticized me because I set a plan I define the scope I sit the outline early on which he claims that it limits my imagination, my innovation, my potential and I have to keep things it's simply more exploratory.

Comment: One thing you need to do:  Look at exiting research and extend it.  So based on A's algorithm:  You can cover new cases, extend to a different field, use more variables, make more efficient, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I come from an engineering background, and work as a professor doing [basic science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_research), so I think that I can understand both sides here.

You are not wrong in trying to approach research from an engineering-practice/project-management perspective. In fact, most researchers I know would benefit from training in project management, particularly in outlining the scope of a project. And a common, and very valid, complaint from grad students is that of [mission creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_creep)/[scope creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep). Yes, grad students get to write a research proposal before they move to candidacy, but these are nothing compared to the minimum standards expected of a project manager in an engineering field.

However, this is the issue from the professor's side: it's called "research" because you don't know what you will find, and it is futile and even counterproductive to try to establish the true scope of the project beforehand. In other words, if you can outline the scope of the project to great detail, then you are not doing research, aka "finding out new stuff."

Here's my recommendation: keep making detailed plans, and keep defining the scope of the project as the engineer that you are, but keep these details from your advisor. When meeting with him/her, use more general language, make sure to mention that you are willing to go wherever the project takes you to. A lot of grad students want to come into a professor's office and say "OK, so if I do 1, 2, and 3, I get a PhD, correct?", but no good professor will agree to that. They will reply with something along the lines of "when you spend 3-5 years exhausting a reasonable amount of inquiries within this narrow subject, and write an acceptable thesis."

Answer (score 3):

##### You appear to be creating a false alternative

It seems to me that you are creating a [false alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma) --- engineering project work *versus* research, instead of engineering project work *leading to* valuable research outputs.
An ordinary engineering project seeks to solve some engineering problem, usually leading to a practical solution in some physical/computational system, or some object/process that you have built/fixed/refined.  For research work in engineering, in addition to creating a practical solution to the problem, you also need to *communicate* your work to other engineers in a scholarly form.  There are a few additional requirements for this in terms of the process and outputs:

- **1. Publication:** After you have solved your engineering problem, you will publish a paper explaining the problem, your methodology and solution, and the results you achieved;
- **2. Literature review:** In your publication, you will need to contextualise your problem appropriately by adding a literature review telling the reader about previous research relating to the various topics under consideration;
- **3. Novelty/Substantiveness:** To be publishable as academic research, some aspect of the problem or solution should be sufficienty novel and substantive that your paper adds to knowledge in the field and has some "value add" for the field.

Nothing in these research activities is in conflict with the parallel goal of doing good practical engineering work on your problem.  Moreover, there is certainly nothing in engineer research that requires "avoiding strict adherence to engineering aspects" --- quite the contrary!  Instead of seeing these things as opposing activities, it is better to see them as parallel activities that augment and support one another.  Good practical engineering work supports high quality engineering research, and good engineering research supports the rigour and quality of practical engineering work.